# FadeOut one element and fadeIn another element on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve an effect where on the hover of an element A, an element B is `fadeOut` and an element C is `fadeIn`, both inside the element A.

That's what I tried:

```js
$('.button').hover(function() {
 info = $(this).find('.info');
 download = $(this).find('.download');

 info.stop().fadeOut(150, function() {
  download.stop().fadeIn(150);
 })
}, function() {
 download.stop().fadeOut(150, function() {
  info.stop().fadeIn(150);
 })
})
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.download {
  display: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <div class="info">
    <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
  </div>
  <div class="download">Download</div>
</div>

<div class="button">
  <div class="info">
    <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
  </div>
  <div class="download">Download</div>
</div>

<div class="button">
  <div class="info">
    <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
  </div>
  <div class="download">Download</div>
</div>

<div class="button">
  <div class="info">
    <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
  </div>
  <div class="download">Download</div>
</div>
```

Hovering one element at a time seems working fine but when you try to hover more elements concurrently the animation it starts to break.

Any solution? Other approaches are accepted. Thanks.

Comment: i believe it is the third parameter of fadeIn() and fadeOut() that is a callback function. the 2nd parameter is ease. try fadeIn(150, 'swing', function(){...}) and same for fadeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inadvertently creating global variables for `info` and `download` by omitting the `var`, `let`, or `const` keywords. That means every function call is using and overwriting those variables. You need to create local variables in each function.

```js
$('.button').hover(function() {
  var info = $(this).find('.info');
  var download = $(this).find('.download');

  download.stop();
  info.stop().fadeOut(150, function() {
    download.stop().fadeIn(150);
  })
}, function() {
  var info = $(this).find('.info');
  var download = $(this).find('.download');

  info.stop();
  download.stop().fadeOut(150, function() {
    info.stop().fadeIn(150);
  })
})
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.download {
  display: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <div class="info">
    <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
  </div>
  <div class="download">Download</div>
</div>

<div class="button">
  <div class="info">
    <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
  </div>
  <div class="download">Download</div>
</div>

<div class="button">
  <div class="info">
    <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
  </div>
  <div class="download">Download</div>
</div>

<div class="button">
  <div class="info">
    <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
  </div>
  <div class="download">Download</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @skobaljic "This ain't working" is not a useful comment, considering the OPs original issue was with the multiple button events. You should describe what isn't working. I've added the extra `stop()` calls so the transitions don't get stuck.

Comment: I just said the original problem `when you try to hover more elements concurrently the animation it starts to break` remained.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is to stop the animation before assigning another. This way there are no glitches:

```js
$('.button').each(function(i) {
    var thisButton = $(this);
    var thisInfo = thisButton.find('.info');
    var thisDownload = thisButton.find('.download');
    thisButton.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
        thisDownload.stop();
        thisInfo.stop().fadeOut(150, function() {
            thisDownload.stop().fadeIn(150);
        });
    }).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
        thisInfo.stop();
        thisDownload.stop().fadeOut(150, function() {
            thisInfo.stop().fadeIn(150);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.download {
  display: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
    <div class="button_inner">
        <div class="info">
            <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
        </div>
        <div class="download">Download</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <div class="button_inner">
        <div class="info">
            <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
        </div>
        <div class="download">Download</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <div class="button_inner">
        <div class="info">
            <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <strong>Mega Limited</strong> 1GB
        </div>
        <div class="download">Download</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyxkLqth/)

Posting this because this may happen to skyline's answer:

[image]

Comment: Good point on the race conditions. Also avoids redundant declarations. Per the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/hover/), `.hover()` is shorthand for `.mouseenter().mouseleave()`.

Comment: Thanks, nice they fixed it, never checked it out. Till v1.2 it wasn't like that.